# Site collection content database

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, content-database

If a site collection content database size grow up; can I add a second Content Database to it? if No, what's the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A site collection have a single content database, we can't have 2 content database for a single site collection.

Now couple of things you can do.

- Clean Up, delete all unused files, items etc. Clear the recycle bin.
- we can also split the site collection into multiple site collections. Like if you have multiple subsites in it than make those subsites a separate site collection n move into different content database.
- Create a new site collection, move the old data in that site collection.

Comment: Thank you! please how split the site collection into multiple site collections? How move the old data in that site collection to new one?

Comment: there are couple of ways to move out the data, using 3rd party tool or export the site and import on 2nd site collection or manually copied the content using open with explorer option. I know it is painfull but yes thats the options. BTW how big the content database right now?

Comment: 400 GB!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: that is big enough for a site collection, i would start with clean up process. delete old / unused content. empty recycle bin. BTW site collection size is also 400GB?

Comment: I don't know? How calculate it !

Comment: go to central admin > application management > Configure quotas and locks...on this page you have to select the site collection to check the quota

Comment: You can also see where your data is within the site collection if you go to Site Settings > Storage Metrics.